# Phonegap Cordova record audio get raw data array buffer

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, javascript-audio-api

I want to record audio on android in phonegap and get an array of floats from -1 to 1.

I've tried the Media plugin but I don't think it gives you access to the raw audio data array.

I've tried recording the audio to file (via media plugin) then loading it via XHR with type arraybuffer but I get the error decodeAudioData error "Unable to decode audio data." But I can load other wav files I've downloaded from the internet, just not recorded ones. I think this is the same issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=482934

I've tried not using plugins, and just using navigator.getUserMedia to record and that works on mobile chrome but doesn't on the same device in phonegap (I guess that's why the plugins exist)